# How to ignore rogue DHCP assignments?

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhcpcd

I have a box connected to a largish local IPv4 network (no IPv6 at all) through a single Ethernet interface; normally, it is assigned an IP address from the `172.16.0.0` range.

From time to time, however, somebody plugs in a DHCP server by mistake, and I get an address from the `192.168.0.0` range (and a bogus set of routes). Is there a way of telling `dhcpcd` (or another DHCP client for Linux) to only accept offers from a specific IP range? Or perhaps a way to filter DHCPOFFER at iptables level, dropping bogus offers?

DHCPCD's [manpage](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html) lists `blacklist` and `whitelist` options, but these seem to apply to the *server's* IP address, which is in the correct/expected range.

I am only in control of this box (and a few others in a similar role); network management is beyond my control.

Comment: Alternatives: - telling people not to plug in rogue DHCP servers doesn't quite work; - setting a static IP and route confuses other, legit network infrastructure; - NATing behind other boxes just moves the problem around, hoping that the other boxes always get a legit DHCP lease.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent or block other DHCP servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/364954/how-to-prevent-or-block-other-dhcp-servers)

Comment: You are looking for dhcp snooping or similar, which needs to be applied to the switch, not the server.

Comment: @TimBrigham: That looks promising...but would require managed switches, I assume? And more importantly, access to those switches - I do not have authority to make such changes. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: So, while applicable in the long term, it's IMNSHO not a duplicate: "How do I fix this on a network client?" "That's not what you want, have someone make a major change in the network infrastructure" doesn't quite solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to configure DHCP clients to only use specific DHCP servers (the point of DHCP is to be dynamic, hard coding which servers to use would negate this), I would suggest configuring the network to only allow configured servers to run DHCP, this then prevents "rogue" DHCP servers from being able to operate.

Comment: Thanks. DHCP is fairly flexible, though - "acquire an IP address from *any* server" is just one of its many `option`s, though. Hardcoding a server still leaves most of the work to that server - which address specifically, routes, bootp, etc. While I agree that "don't do that, fix the root cause" is the most sensible option, I don't have the power to do that.

Answer (score 2):

*Iff* the DHCP server's IP address is stable and you only expect to use the client in a single network, you can use the `whitelist` option in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
whitelist 172.16.3.14
```

A looser possibility, if you know that rogue servers come from a well-defined IP range, is the `blacklist` option:

```
blacklist 192.168.0.0/16
```

If whitelist is used, blacklist is ignored.

Note that DHCP address assignment is a very trusting protocol by default: neither of these are bullet-proof, and wouldn't protect you much: they're simple doorstops against unintentional misconfigurations.